# Why this CTE expression hangs while temp table runs fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have below SQL CTE statement which i found to be a bottleneck for the performance. While debugging, it just hangs there (I think it does table scan) so i replaced it with a temp table and the query runs fine. I wanted to know if there is some difference in the way CTE expression is written which is making the statement hang. I know CTEs have some performance hit attached but i don't think i am doing anything special in the below query to make CTE give me such a bad performance.

```
;with ContList (ContKey, CKey, CreatedDate, DeletedDate, SourceId) AS    
(    
 SELECT ContKey, CKey, CreatedDate, DeletedDate, SourceId FROM #someTempTable    

 UNION ALL    

 SELECT list.ContKey AS ContKey,     
     fact.CKey AS CKey,           
     case when fact.CreatedDate > list.CreatedDate then fact.CreatedDate else list.CreatedDate end AS CreatedDate,    
     case when isnull(fact.DeletedDate, '9999/01/01') < isnull(list.DeletedDate, '9999/01/01') then fact.DeletedDate else list.DeletedDate end AS DeletedDate,                    
     fact.DataSourceDimKey As SourceId                  
 FROM ContList list    
     INNER JOIN SomeFact fact ON list.CKey = fact.DimKey    
     INNER JOIN SomeDimvw someDim on someDim.SomeKey = fact.SomeKey    
     INNER JOIN #contTypes contTypes on someDim.SomeTypeId = contTypes.SomeTypeId      
 WHERE list.DeletedDate IS NULL       
)
```

I replaced the above query with this:

```
 SELECT ContKey, CKey, CreatedDate, DeletedDate, SourceId FROM #someTempTable    

 UNION ALL    

 SELECT list.ContKey AS ContKey,     
     fact.CKey AS CKey,           
     case when fact.CreatedDate > list.CreatedDate then fact.CreatedDate else list.CreatedDate end AS CreatedDate,    
     case when isnull(fact.DeletedDate, '9999/01/01') < isnull(list.DeletedDate, '9999/01/01') then fact.DeletedDate else list.DeletedDate end AS DeletedDate,                    
     fact.DataSourceDimKey As SourceId                  
 into #ContList    
 FROM #ContList list    
     INNER JOIN SomeFact fact ON list.CKey = fact.DimKey    
     INNER JOIN SomeDimvw someDim on someDim.SomeKey = fact.SomeKey    
     INNER JOIN #contTypes contTypes on someDim.SomeTypeId = contTypes.SomeTypeId      
 WHERE list.DeletedDate IS NULL       
)
```

Comment: it looks like your CTE is recursive while second query is not. What is ContList in the second query?

Comment: @RomanPekar : sorry that was a type. Its the temp table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had a (possibly related) situation where a complex query with a CTE would give inconsistent results, depending on which parameters were supplied.

For example:

First Test:

1. Restart SQL Server
2. Run the query with parameter A, get an answer in < 1s;
3. Run the query with parameter B, get an answer in < 1s;

Second Test:

1. Restart SQL Server
2. Run the query with parameter B, get an answer in 64s;
3. Run the query with parameter A, get an answer in 64s;

Turned out that query plan generated for "A" was efficient, while that generated for "B" was not; since query plans are cached, the first query run after the restart of the server controlled performance of all the queries.

Solution was to force a rebuild of statistics for the database.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but i was running the query with the same parameters all the time. I did not rebuild the statistics but looks like it would have fixed the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: While you were using the same parameters, your queries were markedly different - even minor query differences can sometimes result in major differences to query plans, hence my suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A CTE is just syntax.  It is executed.  In a loop join the CTE is executed multiple times.  A #temp is materialized so it is run just once.

Answer (score 0):

Check this QnA and response by SQL Server MVP Gail Shaw:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic415829-338-1.aspx

In short it says **CTEs** are like **temporary views** and when you check the execution plan it is inlined into query. **TempTables** are **tables** created in tempDB.

Tables are faster than views (In your case a recursive view). Hopefully that explains the performance difference between two approaches.